# I cannot save data to the database after creating user authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I cannot save data to the database after creating user authentication on firebase, the following error appears on the console: "TypeError: firebase.auth (...). CurrentUser is null". it seems that the code cannot read the user's uid after creating the authentication

**the code:**

```
createUserButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailInput.value, passwordInput.value)
    var user = {
        nome: "Pedro",
        sobrenome: "Ribeiro",
        cpf: "946.201.340-31",
        uid: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
        email: emailInput.value,
        password: passwordInput.value
    }
    writeUserData(user)

.catch(function(error) {
// Handle Errors here.
     })
})

function writeUserData(user) {
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).set(user).catch(error =>{
    console.log(error.message)
  })
}
```

what needs to be changed so that the code can read the user's uid and save the data in the database?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase.default.auth().currentUser.uid is null after createUserWithEmailAndPassword()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61218790/firebase-default-auth-currentuser-uid-is-null-after-createuserwithemailandpass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not waiting until the new user creation process is complete before writing the database.  [createUserWithEmailAndPassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createuserwithemailandpassword) returns a promise which resolves when the work is done.  It will give you a [UserCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#usercredential) object to work with.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailInput.value, passwordInput.value)
.then(userCredential => {
    // write the database here
})
.catch(error => {
    // there was an error creating the user
})
```

Comment: wow, I put this part of the code and now it's working perfectly, thanks !!